# Meaning for "das ist mir wirklich unangenehm"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expression

On Pons I found that *das ist mir wirklich unangenehm* means *I am really sorry for*, while on Dict.cc I found the translation *how embarassing* (unverified version though). 
I would like to know what it means and how is used.

Comment: According to the site stats on the start page, this is question #5000. Tatatata!! (And really nothing to be sorry of ;-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dict.cc version might originate from phrases such as this:

> Es ist mir sehr unangenehm, euch zu unterbrechen aber …
>   I hate to interrupt you, but …

Which can be used as a way to excuse onself when interrupting somebody.

Additionally it can be used to say that some situation was awkward for you like this:

> Diese Situation war wirklich unangenehm.
>   This situation was really awkward.

The Duden sees those possible ways too ([Meaning of unangenehm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unangenehm))

1. An impression you have:

   > ein unangenehmes Gefühl – an unpleasant feeling
2. An experience you made or will make:

   > Diese Frage war ihm unangenehm. – This question was unpleasant for him.

Answer (score 2):

### angenehm

This adjective describes the positive feeling of being well. When somebody says

> Hier ist es *angenehm*.

then it means something like »I feel well here« (word-by-word: »here is it well/fine«). You might also hear sentences like:

> Es ist mir sehr *angenehm* hier zu sein.

»*It's a great pleasure for me to be here.*« (word by word: »It is me very pleasurably here to be.«)

### unangenehm

The prefix **un-** turns the meaning of each word into its opposite. So »*unangenehm*« means something like *uncomfortable*.

> Walter verströmte einen sehr unangenehmen Geruch.

»Walter was smelling badly.« (word by word: »Walter exudes a very uncomfortable smell«)

But also the phrase »*etwas ist jemandem angenehm*« (*something is/feels well/comfort to somebody*) will be flipped into its opposite by the prefix **un-**:

> Es ist mir *unangenehm* im Auto hinten sitzen zu müssen.

»I feel uncomfortable to sit in the back-row of a car« (word by word: »Is is me uncomfortable in the car back to sit to have.«)

Similar:

> Es ist mir *unangenehm*, dass ich dir den Cocktail über das Kleid geschüttet habe.

»I feel uncomfortable for having poured the cocktail over your skirt.«

The word »*wirklich*« just means *really* or in this context also *honestly*:

> Es ist mir wirklich unangenehm, dass ...

»I feel honestly uncomfortable for ...

But while the english translation just describes the feeling of the speaker, this phrase has in German also the meaning of an apology or excuse. So it also can mean »I am sorry for« or »how embarrassing«. But this depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Die umgangssprachliche Formel "Das ist mir wirklich unangenehm" ist in den meisten Fällen Teil einer Entschuldigung.

- Ich habe leider Ihren Namen vergessen. Entschuldigen Sie bitte./ Das ist mir wirklich unangenehm.